# Castle Windsor IoC property injection. Using property from BaseClass inside ChildClass constructor

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, property-injection

I have a base class as following

```
public class BaseClass
{ 
    public ISomeObject Property { get; set; } 
}
```

and ChildClass inherited from BaseClass.I need to use Property from BaseClass inside ChildClass constructor, but it's not initialized by IoC as I want and has value null. And if I use it inside ChildClass's methods, Property is initialized. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I register ISomeObject in IoC container

```
container.Register(
Component.For<ISomeObject>()
.ImplementedBy<WebSomeObject>().LifestyleSingleton());
```

Comment: How does your configuration look like?

Comment: Do you mean how I Register it in IoC container? Just a minute. I will edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with Castle Windsor but of the way .NET works.  The constructor is run as part of the .NET framework instantiating a new instance of a class.  Only after construction completes can other code (like Windsor) set properties on it or execute methods.

If you want `Property` to be available inside the the child class constructor, then you need to add it as a parameter to the `BaseClass` constructor and set up a matching constructor on your child class.